# How to edit Text Style in List Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List` that is populated with the return data of various `var's` called by a Json API

This `List` also has a fixed `Text` element preceding the data

I want to have separate weight, size etc for the initial text and then the String being passed in

I have tried RichText  and TextStyle but needed a text function, not a list for it to work correctly

Here is the List, which is then passed into a function which pushes it to `ShowDialog` via the dynamic `message`

For example, `Line:` to be `FontWeight.w600` & `$pln` String to be `FontWeight.w400`

```
List data = [
    "Line: $pln", 
    "Departed from: $originname",
    "Destination: $destname",
    "Last seen: $recordedattime",
    ];
```

ShowDialog, where `message` is the `list` from previous function

```
title: Text(title),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(message,
                style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Color(0xff2F2F2F),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ...
```

Update 2 -

```
Future<void> _showDialog(String title, String message) async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff2AC6FF),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          title: Text(title),
          content: Container(
        // Just set a height & a width so you don't receive the previous error
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final titleText = data[index].split(': ')[0];
        final subText = data[index].split(': ')[1];
        
        return RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
           children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: titleText, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600) ),
              TextSpan(text: subText, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400) ),
             ]
           ),
        ); 
      }
    )
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK',
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this where your ListBody is

```
    ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final textData = data[index].split(': ');
        final titleText = textData[0] + ": ";
        final subText = textData[1];
        
        return RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
           children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: titleText, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600) ),
              TextSpan(text: subText, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400) ),
             ]
           ),
        ); 
      }
    );
```

As for your scroll view error

```
AlertDialog(
    title: Text(title),
    content: Container(
        // Just set a height & a width so you don't receive the previous error
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That looks like it'll display how I need but its triggering a list of errors whilst constructing along the lines of ```he following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderIntrinsicWidth#b5c37 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE```. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: ```RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being lazy.```

Comment: Can I see more of the code?

Comment: Have updated question, thank you

Comment: No errors as text in the environment, on compiling on simulator it fails

Comment: ah I see, you can set a height constraint using a `Container` or a `SizedBox`. You need to set a height

Comment: Would that be a ```child:``` above ListBuilder?

Comment: Yes, have you tried using Dialog instead of Alert Dialog?

Comment: Its part of a SDK so I haven't modified it. As there it ```title``` above ```message``` should that have ```SizedBox``` around it to? Where should it slot in, thanks for your help

Comment: Updated the code @al246

Comment: Receiving ```RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1)``` on the line ```final subText = message[index].split(': ')[1];```

Comment: It might be better to create a class for your data points instead of using a delimiter to split the string

Comment: @al246 are all the variables not empty? That might be causing the error if it is empty ```List data = [
    "Line: $pln", 
    "Departed from: $originname",
    "Destination: $destname",
    "Last seen: $recordedattime",
    ];```

Comment: I think I know why this doesn't work. I have just realised the show dialog function is used to populate a pop up marker without the split ```:```. The ```ShowDialog``` is part of the SDK which allows metadata to show. All data is passed in as ```message```, be it my ```List data``` or a String for the opening screen.  So for one use I need to pass a ```List``` in, and another just a String for example. Sorry for not realising this sooner

Comment: Were you able to fix your data? :o

Comment: If I was able to help you with the text styling please upvote. Thank you